# Is it OK to assign a reference to a module to a variable and then use the variable instead of the module?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Assume I have opened a file to read JSON data from it:

```
import json
with open('filename', 'r') as infile:
    data = json.load(infile)
```

For a pickle file I'd use:

```
import pickle
with open('filename', 'r') as infile:
    data = pickle.load(infile)
```

Now I want to be able to use my snippet for both formats, i.e.:

```
import json
import pickle

def read_data(filename, preferred_serializer)
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        data = preferred_serializer.load(infile)
    return data
```

and call it like this:

```
data1 = read_data('file.pickle', pickle)
data2 = read_data('file.json', json)
```

This *seems* to work because both `json` and `pickle` share the same API `load(infile)`. But I wonder whether it works just by accident or whether this is defined behaviour and a reasonable approach.

Comment: Hello. You've not been around much in the Perl tag recently, have you? I saw your comment on aviation re LCY. We should go for a pint while you're here! Drop me an email if you're interested. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fine. Modules are *just objects*, just like everything else in Python.

It's not by accident that this works, it is by design, Python does try to be consistent in naming, so functions that deserialise data are generally called `load`. See [`marshal.load()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/marshal.html#marshal.load) for another example. Or [`yaml.load()`](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation).

If you want to make it more generic still, you can store the `load` function references:

```
def read_data(filename, deserialize)
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        data = deserialize(infile)
    return data

data1 = read_data('file.pickle', pickle.load)
data2 = read_data('file.json', json.load)
```

Functions are just objects too, after all, and now you made your function independent of the name of the callable.